# Any techniques to draw path animated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Is there a way to simulate handwriting using quartz?

I mean there is a path between points A, B and  C. 
I want path to come out of point A and go animated to point B and then C.

What comes to mind is two options to do it:

1. Ugly- Create path then mask it and move mask around to reveal a path.
   Takes a lot of time to create and unreliable and ugly hack
2. move points A,B,C and draw line between them.
3. Some way to animate a circle along a path leaving the trail?

Any techniques, examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `CAShapeLayer` and then animate its `path`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above an ideal API would be one that would let you draw any arbitrary segment along the path but I have not seen any such API.

Another approach would be to define your path is discreet segments. Then use NSBezierPath's element methods to walk along the path and draw each segment along the way on a timer or using NSAnimation. The problem with this approach is that is does not let you use any arbitrary path.

Comment: There's no `NSBezierPath` on iPhoneOS. (There's `UIBezierPath` but it's *undocumented*.)

Comment: Yes, so it is, in that case one could use an array of objects that defined the line from the previous point and then animate along that.

Answer (score 0):

A bezier curve defines a way to get a set of points based on an unrelated parameter, usually called t.  To render the full curve, you evaluate t between 0 and 1 and draw a line from each point to the next.  To render less than the full curve, you evaluate t from 0 to a number less than one.  To animate drawing the curve, you could evaluate the points and draw the segments on a timer.

You can split a bezier curve at an arbitrary t.  Doing that will allow you to pass the curve to the system to draw, or to use in a CAShapeLayer.

A handwritten letter will usually be a series of bezier curves, or a bezier spline.  The end point of one curve is the start point of the next.  Think of t as going from zero to the number of segments in the spline.  If there are 3 curves, think of t as going from 0 to 3.  When t is between 1 and 2, you would pass the whole first segment and part of the second segment to the system to draw.

You can read about [DeCasteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau's_algorithm) for splitting bezier curves.  Here is a code sample for a cubic bezier curve on a plane:

```
// initial curve is four point x0,y0 , x1,y1 , x2,y2 , x3,y3
// x0,y0 and x3,y3 are the anchors
// point to split curve at is 0<t<1

nt    = 1.0 - t;
x01   = nt * x0   + t * x1;
y01   = nt * y0   + t * y1;
x12   = nt * x1   + t * x2;
y12   = nt * y1   + t * y2;
x23   = nt * x2   + t * x3;
y23   = nt * y2   + t * y3;
x012  = nt * x01  + t * x12;
y012  = nt * y01  + t * y12;
x123  = nt * x12  + t * x23;
y123  = nt * y12  + t * y23;
x0123 = nt * x012 + t * x123;
y0123 = nt * y012 + t * y123;

// now the new curve you want is
// x0,y0 , x01,y01 , x012,y012 , x0123,y0123

// the other half of the curve, discarded in your case, is
// x0123,y0123 , x123,y123 , x23,y23 , x3,y3
```

So given a series of curves that describe your handwritten character, you would animate from 0 to T, where T is the number of curves.  calculate t=T-floor(T) and when t is not zero, use it to split the curve at n=floor(T).